# Finding a unknown substring in between of other known (but optional) strings with regex Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to find a name of a place (San Antonio in the example, but can be whatever) in this sort of strings

1. What's the weather in San Antonio
2. What will be the weather in San Antonio tomorrow
3. What will be the weather tomorrow in San Antonio

with this JAVA regex:

```
(What's|What is|What will be) the weather( tomorrow)?( in (\D*))?
```

I get respectively:

1. start() = 0, end() = 33

   ```
   group(0) = "What's the weather in San Antonio"

   group(1) = "What's"

   group(2) = "null"

   group(3) = " in San Antonio"

   group(4) = "San Antonio"
   ```
2. start() = 0, end() = 48

   ```
   group(0) = "What will be the weather in San Antonio tomorrow"

   group(1) = "What will be"

   group(2) = "null"

   group(3) = " in San Antonio tomorrow"

   group(4) = "San Antonio tomorrow"
   ```
3. start() = 0, end() = 48

   ```
   group(0) = "What will be the weather tomorrow in San Antonio"

   group(1) = "What will be"

   group(2) = " tomorrow"

   group(3) = " in San Antonio"

   group(4) = "San Antonio"
   ```

If the sentence finishes always with the city name itself the problem can be fixed easily, I look for the word "in" and the remain is the city name.
But the problem is when in sentence 2 I'm not able to understand if "tomorrow" is present and how to remove it from the city name group.

For regex testing I'm using this page

http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/RegexTester/regex-tester.html

thanks for help.

Comment: Looks like you don't even need a regex for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work for all of your test strings:

```
(What's|What is|What will be) the weather( tomorrow)?( in (\D*?)( tomorrow)?$)?
```

New results (group 4 will always be the city):

1. What's the weather in San Antonio

   ```
   start() = 0, end() = 33
   group(0) = "What's the weather in San Antonio"
   group(1) = "What's"
   group(2) = "null"
   group(3) = " in San Antonio"
   group(4) = "San Antonio"
   group(5) = "null"
   ```
2. What will be the weather in San Antonio tomorrow

   ```
   start() = 0, end() = 48
   group(0) = "What will be the weather in San Antonio tomorrow"
   group(1) = "What will be"
   group(2) = "null"
   group(3) = " in San Antonio tomorrow"
   group(4) = "San Antonio"
   group(5) = " tomorrow"
   ```
3. What will be the weather tomorrow in San Antonio

   ```
   start() = 0, end() = 48
   group(0) = "What will be the weather tomorrow in San Antonio"
   group(1) = "What will be"
   group(2) = " tomorrow"
   group(3) = " in San Antonio"
   group(4) = "San Antonio"
   group(5) = "null"
   ```

Comment: Seems it makes sense, i will test it better next days. Actually this solution can be applied for many other applications, not only weather or san Antonio! Thanks!